# why does exec() fail with empty message-strings?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, xampp, exec

I am using XAMPP on a Windows Server (not in the office anymore, will add exact version tomorrow).

Today I stumbled across this very strange behavior:
When using `exec()` to execute programs some commands work, others fail without giving any reason for it.

```
//working
exec("dir", $output, $retval);

//$retval = 0;
//$output = array with response-lines
```

It seems to work as well with my wkhtmltopdf.exe:

```
//working as well
exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe --help", $output, $retval);

//$retval = 0;
//$output = array with lines from the help-file
```

but as soon as it gets a little bit more complicated, it fails:

```
//not working
exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe C:\other_path\test.html C:\target_path\test.pdf", $output, $retval);

//$retval = 1;
//$output = array with 11 empty strings ?!?!
```

When i copy the exact same string to the server-machine with rdp, and use it inside the windows-shell (cmd), it works.

I have no idea what is going on - imho it's very strange that I get back an array with 11 empty strings.

thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: Every return value (`$retval`) which is not equal to 0 should be considered as error.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes I know. and I know that i got an error - but i have no idea what error I've got - that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the slashes in the arguments:

```
$input  = 'C:\other_path\test.html';
$target = 'C:\target_path\test.pdf';

exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe '$input' '$target'", $output, $retval);
```

You don't have to code it like this, but try encapsulating the paths with `'`.

The above code results to this:

```
exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe 'C:\other_path\test.html' 'C:\target_path\test.pdf'", $output, $retval);
```

You can also try escaping the slashes:

```
exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe C:\\other_path\\test.html C:\\target_path\\test.pdf", $output, $retval);
```

But that's a messy code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! so I should put the variables into double single quotes? I am wondering why you put the variables inside the `exec` string  in  quotes as well, like for example `'$input'`;

Comment: There is no double quoting going on here, $input and $target are literal strings. Double quoted strings accept variables and will revert it to a value and now it has a `'` around it. I'll update the question.

Comment: ok, thanks - i am tired, that's why i got that wrong. I'll have to wait until tomorrow to be able to try it at my office. I'll tell you if it changes anything. thanks so far!

Comment: it was all about the path-backslashes in the arguments, you are right. did not know it would make a difference where the backslashes are. so `exec("C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe C:\\other_path\\test.html C:\\target_path\\test.pdf", $output, $retval);` works. but the best solution is just to use single quotes around the whole string, then you got no issues with backslashes: `exec('C:\some_path\wkhtmltopdf.exe C:\other_path\test.html C:\target_path\test.pdf', $output, $retval);`